# Team Foundation Server: Copy/Merge Model

Tags: tfs

TFS uses the checkout/checkin model, where only one user can make changes to a file at one time. I prefer the copy/merge model (c/o SVN, Git, etc.)

Is it possible to configure TFS to use the copy/merge model? If so, is it a good idea? (I.e. will it explode in a cloud of conflicts at the smallest change?)

Or, as with VSS, is there a way to enable multiple concurrent checkouts -- and if so, is that a good idea?

Comment: -1: TFS does not prevent multiple users from working on a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default of TFS is concurrent check outs, but you can choose to allow only one person to check out a file. Even with concurrent check outs one can lock for check in or check out.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Team Explorer -> Team Project -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control -> Check-out Settings -> Enable multiple check-out. Should default be checked as mentioned in another answer.